# Using BS4 and Regex to scrape email adresse from a website

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to scrape email addresses of graduant students from this page (https://www.math.princeton.edu/people/graduate-students).

I used re.findall and it worked fine (see below code):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re

clg = urlopen('https://www.math.princeton.edu/people/graduate-students')
bsobj = soup(clg.read())
reobj = re.compile(r"\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}\b", re.IGNORECASE)
re.findall(reobj, bsobj.decode('utf-8'))
```

Now I need to do the same task using bs4 find() or findAll(). Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You regex finds duplicates. Here is how you could do it with BeautifulSoup (and without duplicates).

```
emails = [x.a.text for x in bsobj.find_all('div', {'class': 'views-field views-field-field-email'})]
```

First we find every `div` that has class attribute set to `views-field views-field-field-email`. That divs contain e-mail addresses as you can see in html of the web page. Then we get tag `a` which contains e-mail address in `text` from all of that divs .

Comment: Thanks, i know i can do it this way. I just wanted to know how i can use regex with BS4.

Comment: I am just curious, why would you mix regex and BS4 if you can do it in BS4 from the start?